# How to process a '*' in Shell/Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm currently using this code:

```
target_directory_greater="/root/*/"

if [ "${target_directory}" != "${target_directory%%\***}" ]; then
    base_target_directory="${target_directory%%\***}"
    prefix_target_directory="${target_directory##**\*}"

    for t in $base_target_directory/* ; do
        if [ -d "${t}${prefix_target_directory}" ]; then
            # Found, replace target_directory with real path
            target_directory="${t}${prefix_target_directory}"
            break
        else
            continue
        fi
    done
fi

if [ ! -d "${target_directory}" ]; then
    printf "${target_directory} directory wasn't found.\\n\\n"
    exit 1
fi
```

My script will move two folders if grep finds the correct folder which it does. Once grep finds the correct folder for the files to move to, that code above kicks in to process the `*` character in my declared variable and it simply just uses the first folder instead of the one grep pointed to. Does anyone see my mistake there?

`/root` folder has a few other randomly named folders inside there and I use grep to grab a specific string and then move the files solely to that folder. But since there's a `*`, it's causing issues.

Comment: You define `target_directory_greater`, but then use `target_directory`. Is that intentional?

Comment: Yes, it is, unless you spot a mistake with it..?

Comment: It's hard to tell without more information -- what's `target_directory` set to, and what is the script doing that's different from what you expect. Also, try putting `set -x` before the problematic section (and `set +x` after it) to see what's actually going on. See [How to debug a bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951336/how-to-debug-a-bash-script).

Comment: target_directory is not specified completely, we use grep to find the directory we want and grep does find the right directory, but then that part of the code messes up and just uses another directory instead. :p

Shall I pastebin the full source code?

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary, just include what `target_directory` is set to before this snippet executes, and what it's set to afterward (i.e. what other directory is it finding). Including an execution trace set `set -x` would also help a great deal.

Comment: Here's the set -x output: https://ghostbin.com/paste/a93ek

It finds the string in my target folder which is 2FD412E0* and then the code above runs and switches it completely and just picks the first folder it finds.

Comment: According to the trace, the folder that `grep` finds a match in (/var/root/2FD412E0-...) never gets recorded anywhere. Is it supposed to be? Is `target_directory` supposed to be set to it? If so, the problem is that it's not being set after `grep` matches, not that this code is switching it.

Comment: Any idea how we can set to it so that when the files move, they move to the 2FD412E0- folder (the one grep finds a match in) and not the others?